# Is it possible to write a 'no-op' Proxycommand for SSH?

Tags: bash, ssh

I recently edited my SSH config so that the Proxycommand links to an executable bash file, where I want to perform some logic. If `condition1` is met, then I want to perform a certain Proxycommand. Otherwise, I want a "no-op"; essentially I don't want to proxy in this case.

My SSH config looks like:

```
Host *
    ProxyCommand <link_to_bashfile> %h %p
```

However, if I just don't do anything in the bash file, I get the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Is there a way to essentially emulate `ProxyCommand none` when `condition1` is not met in the bash file? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use the `-o` option to override the `ProxyCommand` directive found in the config file, which lets you just run `ssh` without getting into an endless loop of proxy commands. That is, in your `bash` file,

```
host=$1
port=$2

if <condition>; then
    whatever the actual command is to connect
else
    ssh -o ProxyCommand=none -p "$port" "$host"
fi
```

Comment: Hm unfortunately this didn't work for me; it seems to execute 

`ssh -o ProxyCommand=none -p "$port" "$host"`

as a proxy command, rather than the actual command.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the following code works:

```
host=$1
port=$2

if <condition>; then
    whatever the actual command is to connect
else
    exec nc $1 $2
fi
```